# How can I programatically add a beanPostProcessor to a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, post-processing

There's a way to programatically add a beanPostProcessor to a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ?

I can do it declaratively in the xml, but apparently there's no way to add programatically.

My processor must do something like if my bean is a MyInterfaceAware, then do setMyInterface(...).

I need to do it in code cause MyInterface implementation is instantiated in code, it's not available when starting the XML.

I'm using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE.

Thanks,

... this is what I'm doing ...

```
public void setSpringBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = (ApplicationContext) beanFactory;
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) beanFactory).getBeanFactory().addBeanPostProcessor(new BeanPostProcessor() {

        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean,
                String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean,
                String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof RegistryAware)
                ((RegistryAware) bean).setRegistry(ApplicationContextRegistryImpl.this);
            return bean;
        }
    });
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)beanFactory).refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `context.getBeanFactory().addBeanPostProcessor(beanPostProcessor)`

**Edit**

You could use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` also:

```
public class RegistryBeanPostprocessorConfigurer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(getRegistryBeanPostProcessor());
    }
}

context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new RegistryBeanPostProcessorConfigurer());
context.refresh();
```

Comment: The processors are not invoked.

Comment: Add the BeanPostProcessor after refresh(). The internal BF is recreated on each refresh(). If you need the BPP before, override postProcessBeanFactory() to register it. (don't forget to call super)

Comment: Incredible solution. Your code, with little customization, worked as a charm. Thanks.